# Annotating a Bar Plot using pandas DataFrame.plot

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, annotations, data-visualization

I have the following groupby Object , now i need to create a bar with x-axis as the city name and y-axis as the population number i.e. the height of the bar should signify the population number ,along with the annotation on top of bar plot.

[image]

I have tried the below but getting an error in the annotation part.

```
f_pop=df[['city','population_female']].sort_values('population_female',ascending=False).head(5)
f_pop.plot('city','population_female',kind='bar',color=['red','green','blue'],add_legend)
```

[image]

,f_pop is the name of the dataframe and the above screenshot is the first 5 rows of the dataframe.
I am new to Python and have currently started learning visualization.If someone can help it would be great. I am not able to write the annotation code for it

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @HenryEcker I am getting an error while annotating it .

Comment: Okay then will you share that code? Because currently, in your provided code, both `f_pop` and `add_legend` are undefined. Also there doesn't appear to be any annotation code.

Comment: @HenryEcker rectified the post . i am not able to write the annotation code